# Robust Covariance in Multivariate / Multi-response OLS

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, least-squares, covariance

Assume we are in the OLS setting with $y = X\beta + \epsilon$. When $y$ is a response vector, and $X$ are covariates, we can get two types of covariance estimates:

The homoskedastic covariance
$cov(\hat{\beta}) = (X'X)^{-1} (e'e)$, and robust covariance
$cov(\hat{\beta}) = (X'X)^{-1} X' diag(e^2) X (X'X)^{-1}$.

I'm looking for help on how to derive these covariances when $Y$ is a response matrix, and $E$ is a residual matrix. There is a fairly detailed derivation [on slide 49 here](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Ehelwig/notes/mvlr-Notes.pdf), but I think there are some steps missing.

For the homoskedastic case, each column of $E$ is assumed to have a covariance structure of $\sigma_{kk} I$, which is the usual structure for a single vector response. Each row of $E$ is also assumed to be i.i.d with covariance $\Sigma$.

The derivation starts with collapsing the $Y$ and $E$ matrices back into vectors. In this structure $Var(Vec(E)) = \Sigma \otimes I$.

First question: I understand the kronecker product produces a block diagonal matrix with $\Sigma$ on the block diagonal, but where did $\sigma_{kk}$ go to? Is it intentional that the $\sigma_{kk}$ values are pooled together so that the covariance is constant on the diagonal, similar to the vector response case?

Using $\Sigma \otimes I$, the author gives a derivation for $cov(\hat{\beta})$ on slide 66.

$
\begin{align}
cov(\hat{\beta}) &= ((X'X)^{-1} X' \otimes I) (I \otimes \Sigma) (X (X'X)^{-1} \otimes I) \\
  &= (X'X)^{-1} \otimes \Sigma
\end{align}
$.

The first line looks like a standard sandwich estimator. The second line is an elegant reduction because of the I matrix and properties of the kronecker product.

Second question: What is the extension for robust covariances?
I imagine we need to revisit the meat of the sandwich estimator, ($I \otimes \Sigma$), which comes from the homoskedastic assumption per response in the Y matrix. If we use robust covariances, we should say that each column of $E$ has variance $diag(e_k^2)$. We can retain the second assumption that rows in E are i.i.d. Since the different columns in $E$ no longer follow the pattern $scalar * I$, I don't believe $Var(Vec(E))$ factors into a kronecker product as it did before. Perhaps $Var(Vec(E))$ is some diagonal matrix, $D$?

Revisiting the sandwich-like estimator, is the extension for robust covariance

$
\begin{align}
cov(\hat{\beta}) &= ((X'X)^{-1} X' \otimes I) (D) (X (X'X)^{-1} \otimes I) \\
  &= ?
\end{align}
$.

This product doesn't seem to reduce; we cannot invoke the mixed product property because D does not take the form of a scalar multiplier on I.

The first question is connected to this second question. In the first question on homoskedastic variances, $\sigma_{kk}$ disappeared, allowing $Var(Vec(E))$ to take the form $\Sigma \otimes I$. But if the diagonal of $Var(Vec(E))$ was not constant, it would actually have the same structure as the robust covariance case ($Var(Vec(E))$ is some diagonal matrix $D$). So, what allowed $\sigma_{kk}$ to disappear, and is there a similar trick for the robust case that would allow the $D$ matrix to factor?

Thank you for your help.